# How to detect mock location in flutter for ios and android

Tags: flutter, dart, mock-location

I am using package of location and google maps flutter in my screen and I want to detect wether user using fake gps or not.. Is there a package that can detect mock location in flutter that available in android and ios? I have tried using TrustFall package but my app always close unexpectedly.. is there another way to detect mock location in flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [TrustLocation](https://pub.dev/packages/trust_location)

permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

usage :

```
import 'package:trust_location/trust_location.dart';

/* Assuming in an async function */
/// query the current location.
LatLongPosition position = await TrustLocation.getLatLong;

/// check mock location on Android device.
bool isMockLocation = await TrustLocation.isMockLocation;
```

using steam:

```
// input seconds into parameter for getting location with repeating by timer.
// this example set to 5 seconds.
TrustLocation.start(5);

/// the stream getter where others can listen to.
TrustLocation.onChange.listen((values) =>
print('${values.latitude} ${values.longitude} ${values.isMockLocation}')
);

/// stop repeating by timer
TrustLocation.stop();
```

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:trust_location/trust_location.dart';

import 'package:location_permissions/location_permissions.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _latitude;
  String _longitude;
  bool _isMockLocation;

  /// initialize state.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestLocationPermission();
    // input seconds into parameter for getting location with repeating by timer.
    // this example set to 5 seconds.
    TrustLocation.start(5);
    getLocation();
  }

  /// get location method, use a try/catch PlatformException.
  Future<void> getLocation() async {
    try {
      TrustLocation.onChange.listen((values) => setState(() {
        _latitude = values.latitude;
        _longitude = values.longitude;
        _isMockLocation = values.isMockLocation;
      }));
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print('PlatformException $e');
}
}

  /// request location permission at runtime.
  void requestLocationPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission =
        await LocationPermissions().requestPermissions();
    print('permissions: $permission');
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Trust Location Plugin'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Mock Location: $_isMockLocation'),
          Text('Latitude: $_latitude, Longitude: $_longitude'),
         ],
       )),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

for more information you can see https://pub.dev/packages/trust_location

github link : https://github.com/wongpiwat/trust-location

Comment: how about trust location for ios? I also need detect mock location in ios platform

Comment: This package requires minSdkVersion: 21 while we are using minSdkVersion: 18

Comment: @FaizanMubasher This plugin only for Android not IOS

Comment: It doesn't detect on AVD

Answer (score 7):

Use [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and check the Position object's isMocked property.

Comment: Please add example

Comment: @JohnBryan: example available in Geolocator dev page.

Comment: Oh I found it appreciate it, Sir

Comment: It's doc says it will always be false on iOS. What does it mean ? Can location not be mocked in iOS (without Jaibreak) or this property cannot detect it ? Can someone please confirm.

Comment: ```_determinePosition().then((position) { if (position.isMocked) { //.. Show error message return; }```

In case you can find the documentation, here is the code

Answer (score 5):

I think better to use [safe_device](https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device). It's working on both Android and IOS

Comment: it uses trust_location please check example here https://github.com/ufukhawk/safe_device/blob/main/pubspec.yaml, and trust_location only work for Android.